# Fatal error: Class 'IntlCalendar' not found

Tags: php, linux, apache, debian

I'm trying to run the code that can be found there :

http://php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.createinstance.php

for example

and I'm getting the following error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'IntlCalendar' not found
```

My server is running

```
Linux sd-43596 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`php --version` gives me :

```
PHP 5.4.39-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Mar 25 2015 08:33:29)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

and `php -m` :

```
...
intl
...
```

among other modules of course...

and `apache2 -v` :

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Dec 23 2014 22:48:29
```

to finish, it seems the module is enabled, as there's a `intl.ini` file in the `/etc/php5/mods-available directory`

I don't know if I'm doing wrong, I can't get php intlCalendar class working at all ...

Please do I have basic tests/verifications to perform in order to fix it ?

Comment: Well the manual says: `(PHP 5.5.0, PECL >= 3.0.0a1)` you have `PHP 5.4.39` see my point?

Comment: yes indeed... I just saw in the main requirement : [link](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php) `This extension is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0.` ... this means I can use the extension, but not entirely I guess... thank you for your answer.